# Tree-width of a KxK grid

Tags: graph-theory

It's well known that the tree-width of a $K\times K$ grid is exactly $K$. However, on the other hand, we know that the tree-width of a chordal graph is the clique number minus 1. The tree-width of a graph $G$ can be equivalently defined as the largest clique minus 1 of the chordal completion of $G$ (this is from Wikipedia). Combine these two points, we can simply triangulate a $K\times K$ grid by adding a diagonal edge in every square (a cycle of length 4) in the original $K\times K$ grid to make it a chordal graph. It's easily seen that the clique number of the triangulated graph obtained in this way is 3, hence the tree-width of the original $K\times K$ grid is upper bounded by 2, which is a contradiction of the well-known result (the tree-width is exactly $K$ for a $K\times K$ grid).

I know I made a mistake in my thought above, but could anybody tell me what's the mistake I've made?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry- could you be a little more specific as to which claim you're trying to prove?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to prove anything. Rather, I've made a wrong derivation but I don't know where is the mistake. I've wrongly shown that the tree-width of a $K\times K$ grid is 2 by first showing a way to add more edges into the $K\times K$ grid to make it a chordal graph. And then we know that the tree-width of a chordal graph is $\omega(G)-1$. However, the clique number in the chordal graph is 3, so I obtained a conclusion that the tree-width of the $K\times K$ grid is upperbounded by 2, which I know is wrong...

Comment: @daOnlyBG I think I've found where I've made a mistake: the outer cycle of the grid is a chordless cycle of length >= 4, which has not been triangulated by the way I used to add more edges. So the graph I described is not a chordal graph. I hope this helps.